# How to copy movements from one object to another?

Tags: animation, groups

I am learning to use Blender and created a simple animation which shows the rooftop coming off followed by the roof support which then disappears from view. The idea being that a new retrofit support would be installed (thought of using the same support but changing the colour when it is out-of-view but will sort that problem later):

[image: Blender]

Problem is I would like the chimneys and the windows at the top to *group* with the roof so that they will all move in unison instead of having to animate them individually.

Is there a simple method to achieve this?

Comment: if you parent the window and the roof to the roof, won't it give what you want?

Comment: @moonboots - Thanks, will give that a try :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a look [here](https://blenderartists.org/t/copy-animation-from-one-object-to-other/543934).
Basically you can link some properties (one of them is animation) from an object to some other object by selecting all the object (the object that has the animation needs to be the active, so select it at last), then pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.
A dropdown menu will appear. There you can select which property to link from the active object to all the selected (but not active) objects.

Comment: Let me know if it works good.

Comment: Perfect! I selected the `Animation Data` option from the drop-down menu and it works like a charm. Many thanks :)